# What permission is needed to post scores on the facebook friends leaderboard

Tags: facebook

I googled it and I found one saying that I need the permission for publish_stream.
But I couldn't see that permission in Facebook. Do I need 'publish_actions' instead? well, it's hard to get close to facebook. Thanks for any comment.

Comment: Publish_steam doesn't exists. The API call you want to make should tell which permission is needed. But yes it is publish_actions

Comment: Thank u for your clear answer!!!

Comment: @WizKid please post your comment as an answer so David Kim can mark it resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be found in the docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/scores-achievements

> Both the Scores API and Achievements API are only available for apps that are categorized as Games.
>
> Because these API let developers write information about player game state to the Graph API, they both require `publish_actions` permissions, which is subject to Login Review. To retrieve Score and Achievement information about a player's friends, both the player and their friends need to grant the `user_friends` permission.

Comment: user-friends is granted as default. so I need only public_actions. right? Thanks for your kind explanation!!

Comment: @DavidKim: _“user-friends is granted as default”_ – no, it is not. You are confusing app review with actual user login.